# merge a dataframe to a model matrix: R

Tags: r, matrix, merge

I have some difficulties with merging two datasets.
I want to add a dataset to the model matrix, but everything I tried did not work. Hope you can help me out!

This is the dataset that needs to be merged:

```
dput(head(posterior))

structure(list(comp.1 = c(0.06, 0.03, 0, 0.03, 0, 0), comp.2 = c(0.61, 
0.42, 0.07, 0.41, 0.31, 0.41), comp.3 = c(0.33, 0.56, 0.93, 0.56, 
0.69, 0.59)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

To this dataset:

```
dput(head(x))

structure(c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 34, 2, 45, 2, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 29.85, 56.95, 53.85, 
42.3, 70.7, 99.65, 1.47494433546539, 3.27634689625303, 2.03402652377511, 
3.26499480914874, 2.18084241464668, 2.91407858538911), .Dim = c(6L, 
21L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), c("genderMale", 
"SeniorCitizen", "PartnerYes", "DependentsYes", "tenure", "MultipleLinesYes", 
"InternetServiceFiber optic", "OnlineSecurityYes", "OnlineBackupYes", 
"DeviceProtectionYes", "TechSupportYes", "StreamingTVYes", "StreamingMoviesYes", 
"ContractOne year", "ContractTwo year", "PaperlessBillingYes", 
"PaymentMethodCredit card (automatic)", "PaymentMethodElectronic check", 
"PaymentMethodMailed check", "MonthlyCharges", "TotalCharges"
)))
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output. Wouldn't `cbind(posterior, x)` works?

Comment: Weirdly enough it worked, I tried several options that did not worked. But, it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can just do `cbind`

```
cbind(posterior, x)
```